# How can I do something similar to this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I like the way ZDnet has the social sharing buttons on the left side (if your browser is wide enough), but when you shrink the browser, the buttons jump into the article.

Example:
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/mcafee-threats-report-android-is-in-the-crosshairs/63813?tag=content;selector-blogs

Does anyone know if this is a plugin I can download for Wordpress?

If not, is this easy to do in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with window's on resize event. If you look at the source code, `#siu-horizontal` starts not visible, but when the windows gets small it becomes visible. Using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/), you can do this pretty easy:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // Look the page width and show the right div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using media element size so that if the browser's window is too small you make the vertical one disappear using "display: none" and the horizontal appear using "display: block"

Here's a short example to get you started: http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Write your page to have both in html but only to display one or the other according to browser width in your CSS using media-type

Comment: This way you have no JQuery or anything to worry about. It's purely CSS.